# datatypes and javascript... what a nightmare

Tags: javascript, types, jquery

So..

I am passing data to a function that handles strings and numbers differently.

I would LIKE to be able to pass an array of values and detect what the types of each value is.

```
row[0] = 23;
row[1] = "this is a string... look at it be a string!";
row[2] = true;

$.each(row, function(){
  alert(typeof(this));
  //alerts object
});
```

Is it possible to detect the "actual" datatypes in a given row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var row = [ 23, "this is a string", true ];

$.each(row, function (index,item) {
    alert(typeof(item));
});

// Alerts "number", "string", "boolean"
```

Whenever possible I try to avoid using "this" in callbacks and using explicit arguments is usually clearer and more predictable.

Comment: You're welcome. Now I'm going to look in jQuery's source code to learn why your version doesn't work...

Comment: `this` is always an object. *Always*. That is all.

Comment: ...even when you do something like... `var notThis = this` notThis is an object.

Comment: Unless you're using strict mode, but no browser has shipped that yet.

Answer (score 3):

@Rich suggested the best possible solution - use values passed to callback as arguments. Quote from [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> The value can also be accessed through the `this` keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the `this` value as an `Object` even if it is a simple string or number value.

`this.valueOf()` might help you to "go back" to primitive value. But still - in that specific example it's better to use values passed as function arguments.